# Invalid LOC header (bad signature) when opening Excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We met an error while trying to open an Excel file with Apache POI. Calling `new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile)` resulted in:

```
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:369) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:164) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:132) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:561) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:109) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:80) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:125) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart.<init>(ZipPackagePart.java:78) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:241) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:684) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:254) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:201) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:301) ~[tika-app-1.11.jar!/:1.11]
```

However, it's not with all files. Some work just fine.

The Excel files are on a server we cannot fully accessed, so it's difficult to know what is different about the ones that worked and the ones that failed. We thought it could be password protection but nope, a password encrypted file gives us another error.

Does anyone have a hint about what in certain of these Excel files could trigger this exception?

Comment: Sometimes a CSV text file is manually given the ending `.xls(x)` to ensure Excel opens it. xlsx could also be single XML file. So try a text editor.

Comment: Nice idea but it's not that, the content when we're doing a `cat` is gibberish, not like what a CSV file would output.

Comment: Meanwhile, we finally hacked our way and managed to download the problematic file. It's corrupted, plain and simple, even Excel cannot open it. So the whole question might be obsolete fast.

Comment: Maybe an Excel file uploaded via FTP as text, hence transforming \r\n into \n.

Comment: That's it, Joop Eggen! Our client changed their (S)FTP config, and that's what was causing the problem. If you could post an answer with that hint, I'd gladly accept it for future users with the same problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Excel file uploaded via FTP as *text*, hence transforming `\r\n` into `\n`. Instead of the type *binary data* it is.

This can be seen when the upload happens on Windows and the uploaded file is a couple of bytes smaller, statistically by 0.4%.